# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, pydub

Estoy intentando unir dos archivos `.mp3` en uno solo pero cuando corro el programa me sale el siguiente error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Ya revisé la ruta, cambié **`"\"`** por **`"\\"`** y también intente con **`"/"`** pero sigue marcando el mismo error.

Les comparto mí código:

```py
*from pydub import AudioSegment

sound1 = AudioSegment.from_mp3(r"C:/Users/b_rey/Desktop/TESIS/1.-C4.mp3")
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_mp3("C:\\Users\\b_rey\\Desktop\\TESIS\\2.-C4#.mp3")

# mix sound2 with sound1, starting at 5000ms into sound1)
output = sound1.overlay(sound2, position=5000)

# save the result
output.export("mixed_sounds.mp3", format="mp3")*
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: La primera ruta no es correcta en Windows. Para evitar estos problemas te aconsejo que utilices `os.path.join`y así te desentiendes de los separadores